# Spring-mvc requestParam not supports unicode characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

I'm new in spring-mvc, I 'm trying to post unicode characters to my method

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["api/test"], method = [RequestMethod.POST], produces = ["text/plain; charset=utf-8"])
@ResponseBody
fun saveData(@RequestParam(value = "myParam") myParam: String): String {
    println(myParam) // prints characters like á?¥á??á? á??á?£á??á??á?
    return myParam
}
```

It doesn't have any problem with ASCII character encoding params.
I'm testing this service using postman. 
I think I have saw the all questions about this issue, but nothing worked for me, the result is same :/

Comment: And why do you think this is a problem with Spring instead of your terminal configuration?

Comment: Couse I have also tested with debuging, and also passed this param in jsp, which is nicely renders Unicode characters, and also saved it into the database

Comment: All of which suggest that it's `println` that's weird, not the actual transmission.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?  To detect the problem?